# Ubuntu One music app/subsonic and mp3 tag issues

Tags: ubuntu-one, mp3-tag

I downloaded the Ubuntu Music app for android (running v.2.2) and all was going well... I had no problems uploading a couple albums to my "cloud" and then accessing them in the music app, but suddenly it seems like the app won't read the tags on my files and every new file is classified as "unknown artist" on "unknown album" even though I have double checked that the files were tagged correctly.

Is this a known problem? Is any format of tagging specifically not supported?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question...

Apparently the problem has been solved by restarting Ubuntu One on my PC in the system preferences, clearing the troublesome files from the Ubuntu One directory, and re-uploading them. I also restarted the Ubuntu Music app in android again. Everything seems to be in order and functioning fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It's very odd that you had to do that, if it happens again, let me know directly and I'll look into it. My email address is up at: https://launchpad.net/~beuno

If a lot of people upload thousands of mp3 files at once, the scanning can have a few minutes of delay, but I don't see any spiked that would cause this.
Also take into account there is some caching on our end, but only up to 4 minutes.